# Making mathematical sense on a Feynman's path integral equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

Usually we find this relation in the context of Feynman's path integral (see, for example, Maggiore's book on QFT, pg 223):
$
\int_{q_i}^{q_f}[dq] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\bar{q}\int_{q_i}^{\bar q}[dq]\int_{\bar q}^{q_f}[dq].
$

How could this be proved? I understand that the path integral formalism is part of ongoing research on mathematics, but I was wondering if this equation could be proved easily (mathematically speaking). Although its intuitive meaning is pretty clear to me, I can't reproduce it with maths.

Comment: If you're in the QM case, as the "$q$ notation" suggests, the path integral is perfectly rigorous as an integral against the [conditional Wiener measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space). Then your equation becomes the observation that the space of continuous paths from $q_i$ to $q_f$, let's call it $C_{q_i}^{q_f}$, is equivalently written as $\bigcup_{\bar q} (C_{q_i}^{\bar q} \times C_{\bar q}^{q_f})$.

Comment: In this case the result shouldn't be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\bar{q}\left(\int_{q_i}^{\bar q}[dq]+\int_{\bar q}^{q_f}[dq]\right)$ instead?

Comment: No. The measure on the product space is the product of the measures.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the result is perfectly rigorous only for Euclidean time path integrals...for the standard ones there is very little hope :-P